# Formatting an NSDate

Tags: iphone, datetime, rss, nsdate

I am pulling data from an RSS Feed. One of the keys in the feed is is a string representing the date and time the item was created.

I am trying to convert this string value to an NSDate. The string value is returned from the RSS feed as: 2009-11-18T22:08:00+00:00

I tried the following code to no avail:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: [[storedDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"UsersDate"]];
```

Ideally; on top of converting the value to a NSDate value, I would also like to format it using the localised date format on the handset.

Any pointers would be a great help.

Kind Regards

Comment: Is that T supposed to be in 2009-11-18T22:08:00+00:00? or is that a typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve the dateFormat:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: [[storedDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"UsersDate"]];
```

You can use the predefined formats if you would like to format time and date according to the user's locale:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:someDate]);
[dateFormatter release]; // don't forget to release the dateformatter
```

Check the documentation to see which formatter suits you best.

Comment: sorry forgot to answer the question about parsing the date from string. see my updated response

Answer (score 0):

Actually date form in RSS feed may differ, so best way to parse it is following

```
[NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:processedText formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
```

This is not a standard function, library for it can be found here https://gist.github.com/953664